# Trying to get a b-table to handle an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Here the is the b-table, it will display a column of food(s)

```
<b-table :fields="Fields" :items="ITEMS">
   <template #cell(food)="data">
        {{data.item.food}}
   </template>
</b-table>


//The column
Fields() {
 return [{key: 'food', label: 'food'}];
}
```

Currently the data looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "food": "taco"
    },
    {
        "food": "burrito"
    }
]
```

It writes the values all in a single column to the table.

## What I need

I need the table to be able to handle data that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "foods": [
            {
                "food": "taco"
            },
            {
                "food": "burrito"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "foods": [
            {
                "food": "soup"
            },
            {
                "food": "rice"
            }
        ]
    }
]


//The column, probably not correct but I'm trying to get it to read every "food" under all "foods"
Fields(){
      return [{key: 'foods.food', label: 'food'}];
},
```

This would write the data to the table same as before, in one column.

## This almost works!

```
<!-- Everytime a "foods" array is found, loop through all the food items that it holds  -->

<b-table :fields="Fields" :items="ITEMS">
   <template #cell(foods)="data">
      <div v-for="entry in data.item.foods" :key="entry.food">

          <!-- **THIS TEMPLATE DOES NOT WORK, but if it did then it would count as a solution!** -->
          <template #cell(food)="data">
            {{food}}
          </template>


      </div>
   </template>
</b-table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `[ food: 'taco'],` ? This isn't a valid literal.  Also, I can't figure out what you want in the UI... one column, two columns, more? All with the names of foods?  `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.Fields, null, 4))` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.ITEMS, null, 4))` post a short sample of those here so we can see how the data starts out.

Comment: @danh the bootstrap table sees the ```[ food: 'taco']``` and puts it under the column named food.   In this example it would be one single column with all the names of the foods

Comment: No such thing as that.  Maybe you mean `{ food: 'taco' }` ?

Comment: @danh I have supplied the JSON data as you requested, its at the very bottom of the post. Hope that clears things up! And yes I probably meant ```{ food: 'taco'}``` my mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to help, but I can't figure out your description of the data, and I still don't see anything clear about the desired UI.

Comment: @danh I appreciate the effort none the less.... Maybe I'm making it more complicated than it really is? The end result is a b-table with only one single column and all the food as rows (taco, burrito, soup) etc.   But the data has to be organized in a specific way, which is where my problem is. I've updated the question since we last communicated so maybe you could understand it easier now?

Either way, have a good day.

Comment: thanks for the edits. I took my best shot with my best guess about what you have and what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

To get just a single column table with a list of food names, the bootstrap-vue table wants data to look like this...

```
fields: ['food'],
items: [
  { food: "taco" },
  { food: "soup" },
  // ...
]
```

I think I understand from the OP (thanks for the edits) that the source data looks differently. The job, then, is to transform the source data into what the table needs.  This can best be done with a computed prop. The benefit is that the transformation will be cached *and* it will remain reactive to changes in the source data.

This is all you need to turn the data described in the OP into the data needed by the table:

```
computed: {
  items() {
    // presuming source data is available and in the OP format
    return this.sourceData.map(d => d.foods).flat()
  },
}
```

Here's a demonstration of that computation working:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
      return {
        sourceData: [],
        fields: [{ key:'food', label:'The Foods' } ]
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.sourceData = [
        { foods: [ { food: "taco"}, { food: "burrito"} ] },
        { foods: [ { food: "soup"}, { food: "rice"} ] },
      ];
    },
    computed: {
      items() {
        return this.sourceData.flatMap(d => d.foods);
      }
    },
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.27/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.27/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited to include vue/bootstrap rendering of the computation, as well as a small improvement replacing .map().flat() with flatMap()

Answer (score 0):

*This would write the data to the table same as before, in one column.*

To achieve this, your `items` array should be a flat array. Hence, you can convert the input array into a flat array first in `mounted()` life cycle hook and then bind in the `<v-table>`.

Demo **:**

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        fields: [{key: 'food', label: 'food'}],
        items: [
          {
            "foods": [
              {
                "food": "taco"
              },
              {
                "food": "burrito"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "foods": [
              {
                "food": "soup"
              },
              {
                "food": "rice"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.items = this.items.map(d => d.foods).flat();
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.27/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.27/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
      <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
      </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add this answer because you think it differs in some meaningful/valuable way from the answer already posted?  Seems to me that the key insight is the transformation of the input to a flattened list, done with a verbatim copy of the code in the existing answer.

Comment: Hi @danh, Thanks for pointing that out but frankly speaking I did not copy from any answer and this answer is based on my own understanding and thinking. I also added the working code snippet so that it will help the OP to understand in better way. Sorry if it hurts you.